# Unable to download csv file using URL from Digikey

Tags: python, csv, batch-file, curl, wget

I'm currently attempting to create a batch script to download this csv file from digikey(http://www.digikey.com/product-search/download.csv?lang=en&site=ca&pv7=2&KeyWords=SZMMBZ5V6ALT1G&rohs=1&pageSize=500). If the URL is manually inputted in a browser, a download will happen. Is there a way to make a batch script download and save this csv to a file?

I have already attempted wget and curl where nothing gets returned. I have also attempted using selenium in python but the page opens with a 403 error.

```
curl  -o yes.csv "http://www.digikey.com/product-search/download.csv?lang=en&site=ca&pv7=2&KeyWords=SZMMBZ5V6ALT1G&rohs=1&pageSize=500"
SET AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
Wget -U %AGENT% -O yes.csv "http://www.digikey.com/product-search/download.csv?lang=en&site=ca&pv7=2&KeyWords=SZMMBZ5V6ALT1G&rohs=1&pageSize=500"
```

Comment: Maybe you can use their API instead: https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/api-solutions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it ok with vbs ?

```
@echo off

call:download "http://www.digikey.com/product-search/download.csv?lang=en&site=ca&pv7=2&KeyWords=SZMMBZ5V6ALT1G&rohs=1&pageSize=500" "%~dp0thing.csv"

exit

:download
(echo src = "%~1"
echo Set v1 = CreateObject ("MSXML2.XMLHTTP"^)
echo Set v2  = CreateObject ("ADODB.Stream"^)
echo v1.open "GET", src, false
echo v1.send (^)
echo v2.open
echo v2.Type = 1
echo v2.Write v1.ResponseBody
echo v2.SaveToFile "%~2") >"%~dpn0.vbs"
cscript "%~dpn0.vbs"
del "%~dpn0.vbs" >nul
goto:eof
```

Comment: Thank you @Jamailun , but it still seems to pull the wrong information into the csv file.

Comment: I'm afraid the problem comes from the website, not from the download ?

Comment: I'm able to download it to my downloads but am unable to control where it downloads to. I currently have a batch script with: `Start chrome.exe "http://www.digikey.com/product-search/download.csv?lang=en&site=ca&pv7=2&KeyWords=SZMMBZ5V6ALT1G&rohs=1&pageSize=500` @Jamailun

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using start which would open the page and start the download followed by a sleep time and move function to put the file into the proper location.

```
set browser=chrome.exe

start %browser% "http://www.digikey.com/product-search/download.csv? 
lang=en&site=ca&pv7=2&KeyWords=SZMMBZ5V6ALT1G&rohs=1&pageSize=500"
sleep 5

move -----------------------------------------------------
```